# How to make a template cycle?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++23

I'm very often fiddling with cycle and they're almost the same, I think you can simplify a lot of code if you have one template.

```
// the blocks can be different, but the number is known before compilation
const int block_1 = 10,
          block_2 = 4,
          block_3 = 6,
          block_4 = 3;
```

Basically all cycles are like this

the cycle can be like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {

}
```

or this

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {
    for (int k = 1; k < block_2 - 1; ++k) {

    }
}
```

or this

```
for (int i = 1; i < block_1 - 1; ++i) {
    for (int k = 1; k < block_2 - 1; ++k) {
        for (int j = 1; j < block_3 - 1; ++j) {
          

        }
    }
}
```

The number of cycle within a cycle can be a lot, but they are similar.

I think that if I use a template instead of loops all the time, would it be more convenient or not, but maybe I shouldn't and you will dissuade me from doing it.

Ideally I would like a template like this

```
for_funk(block_1, block_2, block_3) {
   // Here I write the code that will be inside the three loops block_1, block_2, block_3
}
```

Maybe this will help https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2374r4.html

Comment: We've already discussed this on ru.SO, and I'm not entirely clear *what* you want from us. An implementation of `std::cartesian_product` matching the paper? Or a macro matching your proposed syntax?

Comment: Sidenote: "cycles" are more commonly referred to as loops. And with "template" do you mean an actual C++ function-template or do you mean macros? Because  your code example looks like a macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can compose `iota_view` and `cartesian_product_view` to get nested indexes in C++23

```
constexpr inline auto for_funk = [](auto... index) {
  return std::views::cartesian_product(std::views::iota(1, index-1)...);
};

const int block_1 = 10,
          block_2 = 4,
          block_3 = 6,
          block_4 = 3;
for (auto [i, j, k, w] : for_funk(block_1, block_2, block_3, block_4))
  // use i, j, k, w
```

[Demo with range-v3](https://godbolt.org/z/eeeT3Wjzj)

Comment: not as short as I would like, but almost similar.

Comment: @user Sorry, what isn't as short?  The `for` loop or the implementation of `for_funk`?